# SQL joins syntax error

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin

Here is my SQL:

```
SELECT product.stock_level,product.name,product.supplier_id,supplier.supplier_name,
from product inner join supplier, 
on product.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id,
GROUP BY supplier.supplier_name,
HAVING COUNT(product.stock_level) < 5;
```

I am getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from supplier inner join product 
>   on product.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id ' at line 2

Comment: Remove the trailing comma `supplier.supplier_name,` before `from`, also in the table name and `ON` clause `supplier.supplier_id,`

Comment: you have comma behind join supplier, delete it, and you have comma behind group by supplier.supplier_name, delete it.

Comment: why don't people just submit answers as answers?

Comment: @W3AVE Because this question will be closed and deleted as a "typographical error"

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski So it's just to not see your score go up and down unnecessarily? It seems like this is done excessively.

Comment: @W3AVE  in cases of typographical errors, pointing them out in comments can enable the OP to get a solution and delete the question before incurring too many downvotes, and before upvoted answers then make it more difficult to delete the question, which has little lasting value to the site. Has nothing to do with my own score.

Comment: THANKS, also i would like the query to give me a stock_level of below 5 but im getting ones with more than 5?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah, I totally get it in your case, which I didn't realize before.

Comment: OP, I don't think you're helping...

Comment: @h21 That is a different question entirely.  And it is probably due to the `GROUP BY` not including several columns from `WHERE`. Not easy to tell though without sample rows from the tables involved, and a sample of the current query's output.

Answer (score 1):

> from product inner join supplier,

Remove the comma at the end =)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT     product.stock_level,product.name,product.supplier_id,supplier.supplier_name,
from product inner join supplier 
on product.supplier_id = supplier.supplier_id
GROUP BY supplier.supplier_name
HAVING COUNT(product.stock_level) < 5;
```

nocomma required after join and group by. ;)

---

What u r doing is grouping the output on supplier name and filtering (using having), ones that has less than 5 (different) stock  levels. If you want to retrieve when stock level is greater than 5 instead, use a WHERE clause with product.stock_level < 5 or a having clause with product.stock_level < 5 instead of count(product.stock_level)<5

Comment: THANKS, also i would like the query to give me a stock_level of below 5 but im getting ones with more than 5? any tips?